# How to count clicks only once even after page refresh - Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, click, local-storage, addeventlistener

I have a page with 100s of links, once you click a link it takes you to an other page. I would like to count the clicks on the links but only once.
I mean if you go back to the links page and you click the same link again the counter doesnt go up.

I have this so far: in js:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("unclicked")) {
        if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
            if (localStorage.clickcount) {
                localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
            } else {
                localStorage.clickcount = 1;
            }
            numberCount.innerHTML = localStorage.clickcount;
            console.log(9);
            event.target.classList.remove("unclicked");
        } else {
            numberCount.innerHTML =
                "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
        }
    }
});
```

And this is the link:

```
<p class="readMore"><a class="readMoreLink unclicked" href="#">Read more</a></p>
```

Right now I am storing the click in localstorage which is great because page refresh doesnt change this number.
But page refresh adds the eventlistener to the link again and it counts the link again once.

What I would like is on page refresh the link still be clickable but not to trigger the counting if it has been visited already.

I would like to do it with just JS but of course any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You'll need to store a unique reference to each clicked element and use them to avoid double counting. You might also look at [`:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) as a query selector.

Answer (score 0):

You could give each link a unique ID or attribute, then once you have clicked on the link save that to a list in local storage. When the user clicks again check whether the ID of the link is already in the list of clicked linked. If it is then do nothing, but if it isn't then increase the counter by one.

In terms of generating the IDs that depends on how your page is setup/generated and whether it is static etc.